# How to trigger a Pubsub.js event in a jest test for react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, publish-subscribe, jestjs, enzyme

I am implementing internationalization in a react application with the [react-intl](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl) library. The language can be triggered in different components, so I used the [pubsub-js](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS) library to publish an event each time the language is changed, and subscrib to this event in my central App Component, which then switches the locale and messages which are displayed in the whole application.

My question concerns writing tests with [jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) and [enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme) which would trigger the language change and have my App component updated with the language, so I can assert that the state variables dealing with the locale are correctly updated. Is it possible to trigger such events, or am I on a wrong path here? My code is listed below

```
//Relevant parts of the app component


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.localeStore = new LocaleStore();
    this.state = {
      locale: this.localeStore.locale(),
      messages: this.localeStore.messages()
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    PubSub.subscribe(LocaleEvent.change, (event, locale) => {
      this.setState({locale: locale.code, messages: locale.messages})
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    PubSub.unsubscribe(LocaleEvent.change);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <IntlProvider key={ this.state.locale } locale={ this.state.locale } messages={ this.state.messages }>
        <div>
          ...
        </div>
      </IntlProvider>
    );
  }
}

// App.test.js

describe('App', () => {
  it('renders without crashing', () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    mount(<App />);
  });

  // This test fails, because the event is not published and the state does not change
  it('correctly switches the language when the language change event is triggered', () => {
    let app = mount(<App />);

    PubSub.publish('locale.change', {code: 'en', messages: {}});

    expect(app.state().locale).toEqual('en');
  });
});
```

Comment: Is the `PubSub` component imported into your module or does come from the global namespace?

Comment: As an aside, this sounds like a prime candidate for Redux

Comment: It is imported into the components which use it.

Comment: OK then I would just mock the import, will write an answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

So you have to mock the `'pubsub-js'` module like this:

```
import PubSub from 'pubsub-js'

jest.mock('pubsub-js', ()=>({
  subscribe:(e, fn) => fn({}, {code: 'de', messages:'someMessages'}),
  unsubscribe: jest.fn()
}))

describe('App', () => {

  it('correctly switches the language when the language change event is triggered', () => {
    const app = mount(<App />)
    expect(app.state().locale).toEqual('de');
    app.unmount()
    expect(PubSub.unsubscribe).toHaveBeenCalled()
  });
});
```

Comment: I get the following error when I try this solution:
ReferenceError: PubSub is not defined.

Comment: How do you import it in your component?

Comment: As you did above: `import PubSub from 'pubsub-js';`.

Comment: But how can you get an error then when it works for your component, strange. Can you remove the mock and look what happens?

Comment: Scratch the earlier error, I must have been missing something. I now receive the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of undefined

Comment: Ahrg, there is a small bug in my example will fix it.